# How to make ammeter with arduino?

Tags: arduino, resistors, current-measurement, multimeter, shunt

i'm interested to make ammeter from arduino. So, i have 70A/50mV shunt resistor and wiring it into arduino.
From my schematic, Is this possible to meassure the current from 12V battery?If it possible then, What the maximum current of this ammeter?
Thank's

[image]

Comment: The circuit you have drawn does not make sense. There is no load, you're just shorting the battery with a shunt resistor, expecting 50 mV but you will get 12 V, the shunt resistor will explode/evaporate and the 12 V will fry your Arduino as well. I suggest you do some research first, look how others build a current meter using an Arduino. You are not ready yet to design your own, you need more knowledge on the subject first.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have done it won't be very useful.
That shunt provides a 50mV voltage difference at 70A.
The Arduino can only resolve to about 5mV.
So, you could resolve 10 steps between 0A and 70A, or 10A per arduino ADC step.

---

As FakeMoustache says in comments, you don't know quite enough to do this kind of thing yet.  You need to do more research.

The circuit you have drawn would pretty much just short out the battery - that could tell you the maximum current the battery can deliver, but you probably wouldn't want to do that with a car battery.

Please do hit google or your favorite search engine and look at how other people have built ammeters with an arduino.

Answer (score 0):

The current limit is 70A, because above that, your shunt will go up in smoke.  As JRE points out, your resolution is going to be very poor.  With that shunt, you'd really need some sort of amplifier to measure the voltage more accurately.

Make sure that you wire the terminals of the shunt correctly, or you'll just end up measuring the voltage across the contact resistances at the terminals.

And heed the comments about what may happen if you connect a 12V battery to such a low resistor.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other comments, some suggested Internet search terms are *high side current sensing*, *low side current sensing*, *instrumentation amplifier*, *difference amplifier current sense*, etc.

Note that companies such as Linear Technology, Texas Instruments, Maxim Integrated, STMicroelectronics, etc. make analog integrated circuits for high/low side current sensing applications. These companies also publish application notes (a.k.a., white papers) that explain the principles involved, and often provide reference designs you can use as a starting point for your own projects.

You can also buy commercial off-the-shelf (COTS) current measurement solutions from companies like [SparkFun Electronics](https://www.sparkfun.com/), [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/), etc. (n.b. SparkFun typically publishes the schematic diagram(s) for the circuit boards they design in-house.)